# QWidget render in thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, render, qwidget

I have a `QWidget` that I need to render in the thread. That's how I try to this:

```
QPixmap pixmap(mywidget->size());
mywidget->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(0,0,mywidget->size().width(),mywidget->size().height()));
```

but it crashes with this warning or error:

> QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Is there any way to render a `QWidget` in the thread?

Comment: You can't render Qt widgets in a thread. But you can render a pixmap in a thread and pass it to your widget (slot that will call redraw)